# JavaScript Class set itself

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, setter, es6-class

Its obvious that class properties can have it's own `get` and `set` functions.
But what about `this`?

As I tried so far, its legal to do something like this:

```
class Bind { 
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
  }
  set this(val) { 
    alert('not sure what happens here!');
  }
  get this() { 
    return this.val;
  }
}
```

so these lines:

```
var b = new Bind(123);
b = 456;
```

should call the setter function, but the alert will never fire.

Any idea what that setter does?

Comment: `b.this = 'a'`  will show the alert.

Comment: I got it! Thanks to Jonas. actually 'set this()' or 'get this()' wont refer to the object itself. but it will create a new property named 'this'!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  b = 456;
```

Cause this does not change the previous value of `b` in any way, it just changes the previously stored reference into a value. A small example of what i mean:

```
let a = {it: "wont change" };
let b = a;

console.log(a, b);

b = 456;

console.log(a, b);
```

If rewriting `b` would change the referenced object in any way, `a` would change too.

---

Instead, You can reach the setter with:

```
 b.this = 456;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        console.log("getter")
        return this._name.toUpperCase();
    }

    set name(newName) {
        console.log("setter")
        this._name = newName;  
    }
}

let bob = new Person('Bob');
console.log(bob.name);// Outputs 'BOB'
bob.name = "new Bob"
console.log(bob.name);  // Outputs 'NEW BOB'
```